# Access files using (S)FTP?

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp, cpanel

Could I access the file like this `/usr/local/cpanel/img-sys/`  by using FTP/sftp software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its simply path from home in linux

sftp is protocol for file sharing

you can access it using [winSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

Comment: when i sftp the server using the root user,but i can't find the file?

Comment: if file exist then it must be seen in winscp, whats problem?

Comment: If it starts with `/` then it's not from the home directory.